# smach subscriber publisher

Tags: ros, topic, smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone,

I'm new to the ROS society, and I have some questions.

I've made a simple state machine,publisher and subscriber as was shown in the tutorials, but how can I use date obtained from the subscriber(e.g a simple String) to make a transition between two states in the state machine??

greetings

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10507/smach-subscriber-publisher/) by [boy](https://answers.ros.org/users/799/boy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2011-07-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A smach state is simply a Python class (see the example in [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/smach/Tutorials/Simple%20State%20Machine)), so you can add a normal ROS subscriber to that class if you want.

This means, in the subscriber callback you can store the message data (a string in your case) as a class memeber, and in the execute callback you can make decisions about outcomes based on tis class member.

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [boy](https://answers.ros.org/users/799/boy/) on 2011-07-07**:
Thanks for the answer Wim, but I still have some problems with it( Maybe its because I'm a rookie) . Could you(if it is not too much) give a small example??

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

This small (and untested) example subscribes on a topic and return success if 2 is received on this topic in the next 30 seconds.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('smach_example')
import rospy
import smach
import smach_ros
from std_msgs.msg import Int16
import time
import threading
    
class WaitForTwo(smach.State):
    def __init__(self):
        smach.State.__init__(self, outcomes=['success', 'in_progress', 'failed'])

        self.mutex = threading.Lock()
        self.two_received = False

        self.subscriber = rospy.Subscriber('/test', Int16, self.callback)

    def callback(self, data):
        self.mutex.acquire()
        if data.data == 2:
            self.two_received = True
        self.mutex.release()

    def execute(self):
        #wait for a maximum of 30 seconds 
        for i in range(0, 300):
            self.mutex.acquire()
            if self.two_received:
                #ok we received 2
                return 'success'
            
            self.mutex.release()

            time.sleep(.1)
            #still waiting
            return 'in_progress'
        #we didn't get 2 in the 30 sec
        return 'failed'
```

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2011-07-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on the *callback-and-loop-in-execute-with-mutex scheme* Ugo mentioned in his answer I made a **fully generic message receiver smach.State class** that helps a lot for receiving messages in a SMACH machine, as I couldn't made use of the the MonitorState.

The current feature set includes waiting, timeout, userdata access and latching, of course optional.

Class `WaitForMsgState` in module `util.py` in unreleased package `uashh_smach`. The class `CheckSmachEnabledState` right underneath is a simple usage example

As the whole class has a lot of (docstring) lines I just post [the up-to-date link to the module's file in the repository](https://github.com/felix-kolbe/uashh-rvl-ros-pkg/blob/master/uashh_smach/src/util.py) (and just for read only reference the [commit-static link to its code line](https://github.com/felix-kolbe/uashh-rvl-ros-pkg/blob/29f03b13b490c9a477f41e047387443bdbea6e16/uashh_smach/src/util.py#L64)).

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-01-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-01-31**:
Felix, I just added this to a new page here to document 3rd party SMACH states: http://ros.org/wiki/executive_smach/AdditionalStateTypes

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-02-01**:
Thanks alot for that cornerstone, that's exactly what I have been missing since I started using SMACH, a way to find existing useful SMACH code. (And what I planned to do after final code and modules cleanup..) I'll add my other states soon!

**Comment by [Tony K](https://answers.ros.org/users/5392/tony-k/) on 2013-07-11**:
Hi, I am doing the same with my Smach machine.